# Error AUtenticacion con VueJS y Firebase

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, vue.js

tengo un error que me esta sucediendo al autenticarme con VueJS y Firebase.
Es una simple aplicación que al autenticarme, deberia redirigirme al perfil del usuario y mostrarme los datos del mismo.
Pero aveces me muestra los datos y aveces no y dice esto:

```
"Error: VueFire: invalid Firebase binding source."
```

Luego me dice :

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "perfilUsuario" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
```

Este es parte del script de perfil.vue, es donde me redirige el método una vez logueado.

```
import firebase,{ auth } from 'firebase'
import mdb from '../config'
import toastr from 'toastr'
import Vue from 'vue'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
import Router from 'vue-router'



let usuariosdb = mdb.ref('usuarios');
var vm = this;
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name,email,photoUrl,usersid,mascotasd;

console.log("USER : "+user);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user,request) {
  if (user) {
       if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        usersid = user.uid;
       perfilUsuario=mdb.ref('perfilUsuariodb').child(usersid).child('usuarios');

        }
  }
});

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  usersid = user.uid;
  perfilUsuario= mdb.ref('perfilUsuariodb').child(usersid).child('usuarios');


}

export default {
  name: 'perfil',
  firebase:{

   usuariosdb:perfilUsuario



  },
```

Estoy seguro que el error esta cuando intenta buscar los valores del usuario logueado con `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` y no los encuentra, pero cuando renderizo varias veces encuentra el valor y el error desaparece.
Mi pregunta es, como hago para que me traiga los valores del usuario antes de :

```
firebase:{

       usuariosdb:perfilUsuario



      },
```

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "perfilUsuario" is not defined` eso es problemas del tu archivo en la app vue. Estas intentando usar una variable que no esta definida

Comment: JBauman, si es asi...pero en realidad esta definida, solo que no la esta reconociendo. Es decir que cuando renderiza la pagina me lee primero la variable perfilUsuario del HTML y luego la busca en el JavaScript, pero no se como hacer en VueJS que me lea primero la funciones y luego las declaraciones en los componentes

Comment: Haz una nueva pregunta, me pasas enlace por aqui y la resolvemos

Comment: JBaunmann Este es el enlace : [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183897/actualizar-componente-en-vuejs] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183897/actualizar-componente-en-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue tan simple como colocar el CDN de firebase en el header del proyecto, y no usar el npm install

Answer (score 0):

De todas es más sencillo si haces la comprobación de `onAuthStateChanged`  dentro del ciclo de vida `created` ya que desde ahí sí tienes acceso al modelo de la instancia y puedes cambiar el valor del mismo y por ende del binding con VueFire. Algo así.

```
import firebase, { auth } from 'firebase';
import mdb from '../config';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import Vue from 'vue';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import VueSession from 'vue-session';
import Router from 'vue-router';

const consultaUsuarios = mdb
  .ref('perfilUsuariodb')
  .child(usersid)
  .child('usuarios');

export default {
  name: 'perfil',
  created() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      this.usuariosdb = user ? consultaUsuarios : null;
    });
  },
  data: () => ({ usuariosdb: [] }),
  firebase: {
    usuariosdb,
  },
};
```

Otra cosa, quizás quieras hacer una comprobación de `auth` en cada ruta (y des-suscribirte para evitar problemas de memoria), en ese caso puedes utilizar un guardián de Vue Router y crear una promesa que envuelva a `onAuthStateChanged`.

```
 function getCurrentUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(
      user => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
      },
      () => {
        reject();
      }
    );
  });
};

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (requiresAuth && !(await getCurrentUser())) {
    next({ name: "auth" });
  } else if (!requiresAuth && (await getCurrentUser())) {
    next({ name: "home" });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```